# Вставить метод isTriangleRightAngled в метод getTriangleSquare

Tags: java

Помогите, пожалуйста. Необходимо вставить метод isTriangleRightAngled в getTriangleSquare.
То есть перед расчет площади метод должен проверять, можно ли построить такой треугольник. Если можно, то он должен выдавать саму площадь, если нельзя, то либо фразу "Нельзя построить треугольник", либо "-1.0".

````
    // метод должен использовать абсолютное значение radius
    public static double getCircleSquare(double radius) // прощадь круга
    {
        double s = Math.PI * Math.pow(radius, 2);
        // S=πR²
        return s;
    }

    // метод должен использовать абсолютное значение radius
    public static double getSphereVolume(double radius) // объём сферы
    {
        double v = 4 / 3 * Math.PI * Math.pow(radius, 3);
        // V=1⅓πR³
        return v;
    }

    public static boolean isTriangleRightAngled(double a, double b, double c)
    {
        if(a < b + c && b < a + c && c < a + b) {
            System.out.println("Можно построить треугольник");
            return true;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("-1.0");
            return false;
        }
    }

    // перед расчетом площади проверить возможен ли такой треугольник
    // методом isTriangleRightAngled, если невозможен вернуть -1.0
    public static double getTriangleSquare(double a, double b, double c) // прощадь  треугольника
    {

//   метод getTriangleSquare должен сначала вызывать isTriangleRightAngled
//   и если он вернет true - вычислять площадь, а если false, то возвращать -1.0

        double p = (a + b + c) / 2;
        double p1 = (p - a);
        double p2 = (p - b);
        double p3 = (p - c);
        double pp = p * p1 * p2 * p3;
        double s = Math.sqrt(pp);
        return s;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println(getTriangleSquare(1, 1,6));
        System.out.println(getCircleSquare(9));
        System.out.println(getSphereVolume(15));
    }
}```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 public static double getTriangleSquare(double a, double b, double c) // прощадь  треугольника
 {
    if (isTriangleRightAngled(a, b, c)) {
       double p = (a + b + c) / 2;
       double p1 = (p - a);
       double p2 = (p - b);
       double p3 = (p - c);
       double pp = p * p1 * p2 * p3;
       double s = Math.sqrt(pp);
       return s;
     }
    return -1.0;
 }
```

Вот, собственно, как вы и сказали. В методе getTriangleSquare делаем проверку. Если можно построить треугольник, то метод напечатает на консоль "Можно построить треугольник" и саму площадь, если нет - "-1.0 -1.0".

Вообще главная задача метода isTriangleRightAngled это сделать проверку и вернуть true/false. Для элегантности можно переписать так:

```
public static boolean isTriangleRightAngled(double a, double b, double c)
{
    return a < b + c && b < a + c && c < a + b;           
}
```

А уже в getTriangleSquare выводить сообщение:

```
public static double getTriangleSquare(double a, double b, double c) // прощадь  треугольника
{
   if (isTriangleRightAngled(a, b, c)) {
     System.out.println("Можно построить треугольник");
     double p = (a + b + c) / 2;
     double p1 = (p - a);
     double p2 = (p - b);
     double p3 = (p - c);
     double pp = p * p1 * p2 * p3;
     double s = Math.sqrt(pp);
     return s;
   }
  return -1.0;
}
```